# Eyebrows in default position in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, particles, sculpting, hair

So, for some reason, whenever I pose the model, the eyebrows move with the mesh. However, when I render it, the eyebrows remain in the default position. Any ideas on how to remedy this? Here is the [model](https://filebin.net/qg7tjm3mn0livfql)
[image]

Comment: Could you attach an image?

Comment: I attached it to the post.

Comment: you should try to upload this to another cloud platform. Google chrome e.g. refuses to download your file due to security risks

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**

It's a clash of *Surface Deform* vs *Subdivision Surface* modifiers vs *Simplify* option.

In the *Render Settings* the `[X]` *Simplify* option is turned on with a *Max Subdivision* value of `0` for *Subdivision Surface* modifiers. This means that for better performance in the viewport all *Subdivision Surface* modifiers are disabled, but active when the image is rendered.

[image: simplify settings]

The disabled *Subdivision Surface* modifier has a red icon. And just to note, it's additionally disabled in the viewport by the "monitor" icon.

[image: disabled modifier]

**How It Breaks**

The eyebrows are attached to the head with a *Surface Deform* modifier. The modifier needs to be bound on a vertex base. This binding was done when *Simplify* was already active. As a result of this, the *Surface Deform* modifier uses the low-poly version of the head (without the *Subdivision Surface* modifier's modification) and the eyebrows are on the right spot.

But when you now render the image, then the *Subdivision Surface* modifier kicks in and messes up the *Surface Deform* modifier and the eyebrows warp around in space.

**Bad News First**

You cannot have the eyebrows fixed in the viewport *and* render *when* you want to use the *Simplify* option. But you can have it fixed in the render *and* messed up in the viewport *when* *Simplify* is on. *Or* you can have it fixed in the viewport *and* render but *Simplify* turned *off*. But you can't have it all.

**How to fix it**

Long story short, to fix it rebind the *Surface Deform* modifier when the *Subdivision Surface* is modifier active and has the correct number of levels.

- in the *Render Settings*, uncheck the `[_]` *Simplify* checkbox -or- set *Max Subdivision* to `1`
- select the eyebrows, and go to the modifiers tab
- there are two *Surface Deform* modifiers, `[X]` remove one. (It's probably a leftover from the join of the left and right eyebrow but you only need one now.)
- here you should now see the warning that the vertice count differs:
  [image: surface deform modifier]
- click the <kbd>Unbind</kbd> button, the button will change.
- click the <kbd>Bind</kbd> button to rebind

That's it. Done.

Keep in mind that the "*Subsurf*" modifier on the body/head must have the same number of levels for the viewport and the render. And that you need to rebind the *Surface Deform* each time when you change the number of levels.

Comment: Wow. I'm gonna have to get that a try, when I get back to working on Blender. Thanks.